# LWC Error Invalid reference

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, debugging, js, reference

I have js file in the lwc that keeps giving me the Error Invalid reference, but it still works 100%, i just can't make new changes.
I would like to add a validation that there has to be something in the notes field before being able to click the button "took place" but i can't work on the js file.

```
 import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

import markTookPlace from '@salesforce/apex/TreatmentEventsController.markTookPlace';
import unmarkTookPlace from '@salesforce/apex/TreatmentEventsController.unmarkTookPlace';

import TREATMENT_EVENT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Treatment_Event__c';
import DOCTOR_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Treatment_Event__c.Doctor__c';
import NOTES_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Treatment_Event__c.Notes__c';
import GUIDE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Treatment_Event__c.Guide__c';

export default class TreatmentEventInfo extends LightningElement {
  @api event;

  @track treatmentEventObject = TREATMENT_EVENT_OBJECT;
  @track doctorField = DOCTOR_FIELD;
  @track notesField = NOTES_FIELD;
  @track guideField = GUIDE_FIELD;
  @track showUpdateNotesButton = false;

  get upcomingEvent() {
    return new Date(this.event.startDate) > new Date();
  }

  toggleSection(event) {
    const eventId = event.target.dataset.eventId;

    this.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('togglesection', {
        detail: eventId,
      }),
    );
  }

  handleDoctorChange() {
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit();
  }

  handleNotesChange() {
    this.showUpdateNotesButton = true;
  }

  handleSuccessDoctorChange() {
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('doctorchange', {}));
  }

  handleSuccessNotesChange() {
    this.showUpdateNotesButton = false;
  }

  handleTookPlace() {
    markTookPlace({ eventId: this.event.id })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'An error occured',
            message: error.body.message,
            variant: 'error',
          }),
        );
      })
      .finally(() => this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('statuschanged', {})));
  }

  handleUntookPlace() {
    unmarkTookPlace({ eventId: this.event.id })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'An error occured',
            message: error.body.message,
            variant: 'error',
          }),
        );
      })
      .finally(() => this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('statuschanged', {})));
  }
}
```